# Java: ServerSocket ErrorMessage

Tags: java, server, serversocket

I've just tried to implement my first Server, but Java doesn't seem to recognize my ServerSocket Constructor in the try-with-resources block.

what is wrong with the following code?

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerSocket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Error message Eclipse:

> - constructor of Serversocket(int) is undefined
> - the type ServerSocket is not visible
> - the resource does not implement AutoClosable

```
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777)) {  
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

            DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);

            String receivedMessage;
            receivedMessage = dataIn.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Server received from Client: " + receivedMessage);
            dataOut.writeUTF(receivedMessage);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: solved. a stupid name clash was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your class.

It's conflicting with the ServerSocket class in the JDK, which is the one you want to use in the try-with-resources.

Comment: never made such a stupid mistake before. thank's for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a name clash between your own `ServerSocket` class and the one you're trying to use.

Call it something else, and don't do that.